# Redirect from "private" page and functions.php which tag add to add_action()?

Tags: functions

If someone try to open a private page as guest user he says only "Oops! That page can’t be found.", I want to redirect it to a exact page, I try to do it in functions.php but I'm confused what to add as $tag in add_action() and how to do this redirect?

```
add_action( 'WHAT_TO_ADD', 'private_post_redirect' );
function private_post_redirect()
{
    global $ID;

    if (!is_user_logged_in() ) :
        if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'private' ) :
            echo '<h1>private - functions.php</h1>';
        else :
            echo '<h1>public - functions.php</h1>';
            //wp_redirect( '/login/' ); exit;
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: `template_redict` === "WHAT_TO_ADD"

Comment: @PieterGoosen if I add this then is no one "echo" option as output visible but also no redirect...

Comment: [There are plenty of info on this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp_redirect%20template_redirect). Be sure to use the site search. Also, where is $ID coming from

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Global 
You should try this:

```
    function redirect_private_content() {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $current_query = $wpdb->get_row($wp_query->request);
        if( 'private' == $current_query->post_status ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('/') );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_private_content', 9 );
```